# Accessing the value of a setTimeout promise without awaiting it

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am writing some code to simulate a Database call that I only want to make once, and store the result in a map (to prevent repeated round trips).

My code seems to work fine, but I am getting an unexpected result: when I remove one of the await values (highlighted below), the code appears to wait on the resolution of the promise (in that the console.log still waits for 5 seconds), but the logged value is still a Promise.

In my mind, this seems inconsistent, so I think my understanding of Promises might be lacking.

```js
const inputs = ['a', 'b'];

let promiseOrValue

async function processor(input){
    if (promiseOrValue){
        await promiseOrValue
    }
    else {
        promiseOrValue = asyncFunction()
        await promiseOrValue
    }
    console.log(`${input} ${**await** promiseOrValue}`)
}

async function asyncFunction(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('resolving')
            resolve('foo')
        }, 1000)
    })
}

inputs.forEach(processor)
```

I expect that either the console.log will print immediately with `[object Promise]`, or it will wait 5 seconds and print `foo`. In fact, it waits 5 seconds, and then prints `[object Promise]`.

Comment: Higher in that function you're doing `await promiseOrValue` anyway, so that's why you're waiting in either case.

Comment: A Promise object just promises that you will get a value at some point in the future. If you aren't going to *wait* for that value, then of course you'll get the promise and not the value.

Comment: `.forEach()` does NOT pause for `await` inside its callback.  So your `.forEach()` loop runs immediatley to completion which does not seem likely it's what you want.  This code looks generally confused.  You'd probably get better help with a good design if you backed up and described a little more exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you just trying to build a database cache for recently retrieved values so you can fetch a value  from the cache if it's been recently retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have awaited for `promiseOrValue` but don't assign its return data to any variable. So the process will be paused until `promiseOrValue` done.

```
await promiseOrValue;
```

You need to remove `await` to not pause your process.

Comment: Thanks Tien. I think my assumption was that `await` mutated the value that is passed to it, but that must not be the case.

Comment: @RichardCoates - No, `await` pauses the execution of that function until the promise you await resolves.  The first `await` inside an `async` function  causes that `async` function to pause and also immediately return a promise that will eventually be resolved when the function returns its final value.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I understand that, what confuses me is that promiseOrValue is assigned a promise, which we've then awaited, but when we log it, it's still a promise, not a value.

Comment: @RichardCoates - `promiseOrValue` never changes it's own value because of `await`.  It's a promise.  That's what it is.  If you want the value out of it, you do `let value = await somePromise`.  I'd suggest reading a few introductory tutorials on the use of `await`.  You are missing a fundamental core concept for how it works with promises.